# App rejected from app store due to Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios

I have submitted an app on Appstore.

The app got rejected and here is the Apple Response

We noticed that your app requires users to register or log in to access features that are not account-based.

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to let users freely access your app’s non-account-based features.

Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law.

You should allow users to freely access your app’s non-account-based features. For example, an e-commerce app should let users browse store offerings and other features that are not account-based before being asked to register, or a restaurant app should allow users to explore the menu before placing an order. Registration must then only be required for account-specific features, such as saving items for future reference or placing an order.

Please guide me to overcome this issue

Comment: As mentioned in Apple's review , your app was rejected because you are making the users register (asking for personal details) for non account based features. So if you have a valid reason for making the users register. Submit a reply to Apple's Team clearing stating the reason for why you are making the users register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change in your app flow. User can view all features(like stores, restaurants) without login. User will enter his personal details only when it is necessary for particular feature.